# Show that if A and B are strictly convex, then A + B is strictly convex or provide a counter example.

Tags: convex-analysis, economics

We have:
If A is open:
 $\exists x,y \in A,$  $x \neq y$  such that $\lambda x+(1-\lambda y)\in \dot A  $ (the interior) and
$\exists u,v \in B,$  $x \neq y$  such that $\lambda u+(1-\lambda v)\in \dot B$.
\begin{equation}
\lambda (u+x)+(1-\lambda (v+y))\in \dot(A+B) ...(interior)
\end{equation}
How would we show this for a concave function such as the unit circle?